# Jquery: why does my products have the same data-price as the first product?

Tags: jquery, magento

Sorry i couldn't add the picture(First time asking question in Stackoverflow )

What i want is to put products in the bucket and then add the price together for every product in the bucket.

I have a problem with the products that doesn't  use their own data-price.

So my first product has a data-price "75". But the other products have other data-prices. But they all give the data-price "75".

http://jsbin.com/tabunuzava/edit?html,output

Comment: Welcome @Mil0, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's very unclear what you want ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)